# Realtime visitors online - multiple websites NodeJS, Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have working code for realtime dashbord shows current online visitors on my web. I want implement possibility for usage on multiple websites.

**WEB A - client.js**

```
var socket = io("ip:port", {reconnection: false});
socket.on('connect', function() {
   socket.emit('join', 'room1'); 
});    
var visitorData = {
  referringSite: document.referrer,
  page: location.pathname,
  room: 'room1'
}
socket.emit('visitor-data', visitorData);
```

**WEB B - client.js**

is same as **WEB A** but there is

```
socket.emit('join', 'room2');
```

**Server script app.js**

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){    

    socket.on('join', function(room) {
            socket.join(room);
            io.to(room).emit('updated-stats', computeStats());                            
    });

    socket.on('visitor-data', function(data) {
       visitorsData[socket.id] = data;   
       io.to(data.room).emit('updated-stats', computeStats());
     });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(data) {
     delete visitorsData[socket.id];   
     io.in(room).emit('updated-stats', computeStats());  
  }); 

});
```

**Admin panel WEB A (here is dashboard)**

```
var socket = io("server:port");
socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.emit('join', 'room1'); //there i need data only from room1
});    

socket.on('updated-stats', function(data) {
    console.log(data.pages);
    $(".online").html(data.activeUsers);
});
```

My problem is - in admin panel of **WEB A** i getting stats from WEB A and WEB B **together**. I need data separated for WEB A and WEB B. Is it possible to do this when join same ip and same port? I dont want to create node instance for individual website separated.

Comment: If WEB B is the same as WEB A except for `socket.emit('join', 'room2');` you have to change 'room1' to 'room2' in `var visitorData` in WEB B.

Comment: Sorry, that's i have already set. But still getting data from sites together. I need data separated from WEB A and WEB B.

Comment: So you can change computeStats function to return active users for each room based on visitorData.room The structure could look like `[{room:'room1',activeUsers:123}, {room:'room2', activeUsers:456}]`